# Bash end command after selection

Tags: bash

Trying to understand why that when I call this function it does not end

```
function_call () {
    while true; do
        read -p "Do you wish to do this?" yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) command1 && command2 && exit 0 ;;
            [Nn]* ) break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
        esac
    done
}
```

On the Y, it should run the commands then exit. On N, it should continue running the rest of the script.

Not sure if the `&&` is needed, but when I run it if I hit Y it runs the command, but continues.

Comment: BTW, in addition to what's in Benjamin's answer, whether `exit` causes your primary shell to exit depends on details not given here -- such as whether the code in question is run in a subshell. Sometimes that's not even well-defined and depends on shell implementation details -- `cat /dev/tty | function_call`, for instance, would put `function_call` in a subshell on bash (in an out-of-the-box configuration -- but not if `lastpipe` is enabled and operational), but not in ksh.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `&&`, `exit 0` is only executed if both `command1` and `command2` exit with status 0, i.e., successfully. Depending on what they are/do and how they succeed, `exit` does *not* get called and your script just continues.

To avoid that, you can replace the last `&&` with `;`. Consider:

```
$ true && false && echo "Yes"    # echo not called
$ true && false; echo "Yes"
Yes
```